# How do I extract Month and Year in a MySQL date and compare them?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How do I extract the month and date from a mySQL date and compare it to another date?

I found this MONTH() but it only gets the month. I looking for month and year.

Comment: There is a YEAR function too.

Comment: @zerkms DATE_FORMAT() worked perfectly. I'd give you the correct answer. Would you mind explaining the difference between %c, %d and %e? %c worked fine but the last 2 gave me an incorrect date.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m') works as well as EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date)

Answer (score 97):

in Mysql Doku: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `date` ) 
FROM `Table` WHERE Condition = 'Condition';
```

Comment: Can it please be explained when `EXTRACT` is preferred versus `DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: This works well in mysql, but not in Java,  use DATE_FORMAT in java

Answer (score 92):

While it was discussed in the comments, there isn't an answer containing it yet, so it can be easy to miss.
DATE_FORMAT works really well and is flexible to handle many different patterns.

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m')
```

To put it in a query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(test_date,'%Y%m') AS date FROM test_table;
```

Answer (score 40):

If you are comparing between dates, extract the full date for comparison. If you are comparing the years and months only, use

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS 'year', MONTH(date) AS 'month'
 FROM Table Where Condition = 'Condition';
```

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * FROM Table_name Where Month(date)='10' && YEAR(date)='2016';
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the mySQL docs in regard to the date functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

There is a YEAR() function just as there is a MONTH() function. If you're doing a comparison though is there a reason to chop up the date? Are you truly interested in ignoring day based differences and if so is this how you want to do it?

Comment: Im trying to get the month and year for now.

Answer (score 1):

There should also be a YEAR().

As for comparing, you could compare dates that are the first days of those years and months, or you could convert the year/month pair into a number suitable for comparison (i.e. bigger = later). (Exercise left to the reader. For hints, read about the ISO date format.)

Or you could use multiple comparisons (i.e. years first, then months).

Comment: Dates can be compared without math :-)

Comment: oh yeah, let me add that too.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `dateformat()` could come handy here.

Example:
For a column `'date'` with example datetime: 12-01-2023

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')
```

will yield: `12-2023`