# Mysql date year and month information

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT user_guid, test_name, subcategory_name
FROM complete_tests
WHERE YEAR(created_at) ='2014' AND MONTH (created_at) = '10' LIMIT 100;
```

When coding with mySQL and using WHERE for the date info, is the "created_at" specific to the tables i am working with or will i always use (created_at)?

Comment: Be aware that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless, and this kind of query cannot use an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this query the created_at field is relative to the table complete_tests. It will work only if created_at is a DATE or DATETIME type field.

More information if you want to improve your knowledge about MySQL date and time functions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

[How do I extract Month and Year in a MySQL date and compare them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830987/how-do-i-extract-month-and-year-in-a-mysql-date-and-compare-them)