# Count All for a specific Month using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datepicker

I am currently doing an e-commerce system. I would like to monitor how many people bought to the specific product in that month.. For example I am selling earphones, 5 people bought earphones for the month of January,Feb and so on.

Question: Is it possible to split the mm in my stored value in my table?

NOTE: I used the datepicker in html(the format of datepicker in html is yyyy-mm-dd)

**CONTROLLER**

```
$data['products'] = $this->CrudModel->count_all('products','date');
print_r($data['products']);die;
```

**MODEL**

```
public function count_all($table,$date)
{
    $this->db->select('product_name');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where(array('date' => '$date' )); // What should I put here? So that I can fetch the date starting January until December
    $num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

**COLUMNS of my PRODUCT Table**

```
'event_id' 'full_name' 'email' 'date' 'contact'
```

Comment: you can use group by.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. How sir?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$this->db->where('date >=', $start_date);
$this->db->where('date <=', $end_date);
```

or you can also try

```
$where = "DATE(date) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-02-01'";
```

Comment: Sir is it possible to split the mm in my stored value that I used date picker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by like below

```
public function count_all($table,$date)
{
    $this->db->select('product_name');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where('date >=', $start_date);
    $this->db->where('date <=', $end_date);
    $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
    $this->db->group_by('MONTH(date), YEAR(date)');
    $num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. What is the meaning of this? " ('MONTH(date), YEAR(date)') "

Comment: These are mysql Date functions, Month(date) will return month of date and year will return year. you can split your store date  into mm and YY. For more info.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830987/how-do-i-extract-month-and-year-in-a-mysql-date-and-compare-them

Comment: What is the name of your date column? Could you show some row data from your Db for date.

Comment: $this->db->where('date >=', $start_date);
 $this->db->where('date <=', $end_date); 
try removing where clause.
And why you are using count_all_results() ? you want count only ?

Comment: All the items bought during that month.. It stated in my description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137921/discussion-between-shafiq-and-angel).