# PHP: Select data summed from months of a year

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a restaurant web manager.
I need to get the total of all the months of a year.
Do I need to make a query for each month, or there is a way to make it all in one query with a FOR (loop). 
Each month has different orders with different values which has to been summed to the month to show them separatedly.
I can't get a clue of how to do it if it's not with each month one by one.

I think this way may get it.

```
for ($sum=0; $sum < 12; $sum++) { 
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT table_number, SUM(price) as totalprice FROM orders WHERE MONTH(dates) = '$sum' && YEAR(dates) = '$year' GROUP BY table_number");
}
```

I have a mysql database. 
The orders are placed on a table "orders" whith following structure:

.id(int)
.name(varchar)
.price(int)
.table_number(int)
.date (date / Y.m.d)

Comment: Show us your code and explain what's wrong with it

Comment: Theres no code, i'm trying to get a clue how to do it.

Comment: Please show us some code. If you don't have any yet Start searching about `Extracting Month or Year from Datetime in Mysql` and then write a group by query with SUM(the column you want to be summed). And then, paste here your code if you can not get it working. And here is an answer with 1sec google search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830987/how-do-i-extract-month-and-year-in-a-mysql-date-and-compare-them

Comment: Have a date column in your table and JOIN a subquery with 12 ints representing the months(in case you have missing months) and group by month,year. FUnction MONTH(dateCol) returns an int from 1 to 12.

Comment: I think this might help

for ($sum=0; $sum < 12; $sum++) { 
  $date = date("m");
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT table_number, SUM(price) as totalprice FROM orders WHERE MONTH(dates) = '$date' && YEAR(dates) = '$year' GROUP BY table_number");
 }

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a MySQL database. And I assume you have one table where all orders are stored. I assume you have a field `value` (`double`) and a field `time` (`timestamp`). Try

```
SELECT
  YEAR(`time`), MONTH(`time`), SUM(`value`)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY YEAR(`time`), MONTH(`time`)
ORDER BY YEAR(`time`) ASC, MONTH(`time`) ASC;
```

Also check the MySQL manual:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a table of whatever you want to sum. Add a column in it of the data you want to sum for each month and add another column in the table which stores the month every row belongs to.
Now query this table with php to get all the rows of the table and make an arrray of all the months, check which month every row belongs to and add the data you want to sum to that specific months total summation.
Like this, you can easily find the sum for each month and can achieve what you are trying to do.