# select from mysql Table a string that contains slash

Tags: java, mysql

How to select in mysql a a value for ex: "1/2019" ?

as **select * from table where column = "1/9099"** is not working properly

Comment: What is the data type of this column?

Comment: How do you know that the column contains a slash?

Comment: varchar(10) in DB and String in java class

Comment: @PaulSpiegel it has a pattaern that only permits number slash 4 numbers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830987/how-do-i-extract-month-and-year-in-a-mysql-date-and-compare-them

Comment: @OldProgrammer it is not a adate it is just a simple string

Comment: Why tag "java"? Are you doing this in JDBC? If so, post the code and define "not working properly".

Comment: @NestorSokil in spring and hibernate

Comment: @TitoTito How does the pattern look like? Where did you define it. How is it enforced? And what does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: "not working properly" is not a problem description. That query should work besides 9099 != 2019

Comment: @f1sh Yup, [it seems to work even with double quotes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0dd701e716ad97e429b0f2b4fb42e071).

Answer (score 2):

The following query should run completely OK on MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '1/9099';
```

Note that I placed *single* quotes around the string literal, not double quotes.  Double quotes in ANSI SQL are intended to placed around identifiers, such as table or column names.  There is nothing about a forward slash which has any special meaning in a MySQL string literal.

If this answer does not completely resolve your problem, then maybe include your Java/JDBC/Hibernate code.

Also note that `column` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.  This answer assumes that `column` in the query is just a placeholder for some other name.

Answer (score 0):

If the data type is DATE you can use something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH( column ) = '1' AND YEAR( column ) = '2019';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this is Java then there may be a problem with quotation marks.

```
String sql = "select * from table where column = '1/9099'";
```

Or try

```
String sql = "select * from table where column = \"1/9099\"";
```

The slash should not be a problem for MySQL (or any other system if it's not a UNIX path).